# Maven dependency for Servlet 3.0 API?

Tags: java, maven-2, servlets, jakarta-ee

How can I tell Maven 2 to load the Servlet 3.0 API?

I tried:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I use http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/ but what repository would be correct?

**Addendum:**

It works with a dependency for the entire Java EE 6 API and the following settings:

```xml
<repository>
    <id>java.net</id>
    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I'd prefer to only add the Servlet API as dependency, but "Brabster" may be right that separate dependencies have been replaced by Java EE 6 Profiles. Is there a source that confirms this assumption?

Comment: No sources, no javadocs in java.net/maven/2 repository. Oracle, go to hell!

Comment: Using javaee-Api instead of servlet-api does not give you the same version of javax.servlet.ServletContext. I am using spring framework 3.1 and using dynamic dispathcer (annotation). Sa'ad's answer is the only answer that works for me. You really should not go with Pascal as that seems to be more generic. Heck.. gradle beats maven in resolving dependencies.

Comment: OMG, they changed the **artifact name** from `servlet-api` to `javax.servlet-api`. Lost half an hour "debugging"... :/

Answer (score 117, accepted):

> I'd prefer to only add the Servlet API as dependency,

To be honest, I'm not sure to understand why but never mind...

> [Brabster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2362/brabster) separate dependencies have been replaced by Java EE 6 Profiles. Is there a source that confirms this assumption?

The maven repository from Java.net indeed offers the following artifact for the WebProfile:

```xml
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>java.net2</id>
    <name>Repository hosting the jee6 artifacts</name>
    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>        
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This jar includes Servlet 3.0, EJB Lite 3.1, JPA 2.0, JSP 2.2, EL 1.2, JSTL 1.2, JSF 2.0, JTA 1.1, JSR-45, JSR-250.

But to my knowledge, nothing allows to say that these APIs won't be distributed separately (in java.net repository or somewhere else). For example (ok, it may a particular case), the JSF 2.0 API is available separately (in the java.net repository):

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0-b10</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And actually, you could get `javax.servlet-3.0.jar` from [there](http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/org/glassfish/javax.servlet/3.0) and install it in your own repository.

Comment: One small correction: javaee-web-api includes EL 2.2 (Unified Expression Language 2.2), not EL 1.2

Comment: ... and for gradle use:  compile 'javax:javaee-web-api:6.0'

Comment: Note that `javaee-web-api` only contains method stubs (no byte code). You cannot use this dependency outside the `provided` scope which is why I prefere the suggestion of Sa'ad.

Comment: @Pascal - "I'd prefer to only add the Servlet API as dependency" - you would do that if you are dealing with a pure servlet container (tomcat, jetty) vs a JEE compliant container (TomEE, wildfly, etc)

Comment: As JoD. said, it makes sense to add the Servlet API alone when you don't need "EJB Lite 3.1, JPA 2.0, JSP 2.2, EL 1.2, JSTL 1.2, JSF 2.0, JTA 1.1". For example, that is my need, for [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) development.

Comment: the **javaee-web-api** has been updated to `<version>7.0</version>`

Answer (score 467):

This seems to be added recently:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1/

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hey, This works fine but I'm not sure this is the exact dependency to be used (with Tomcat 7 for example); the reason is that the sources attached to this dependency do not match what's actually running when you actually do debugging.

Comment: What does the scope provided mean?

Comment: @TejaswiRana Provided scope means that it is not packaged to war. The dependency is available at compile time, you expect it in the server library folder.

Comment: Why didn't it just reuse the artifactId `servlet-api`? Because it's fun to add `<excludes>` for the old artifactId (in order to prevent getting both the old and new servlet api on your classpath if one of your dependencies still depends on the old one)? :)

Comment: Geoffrey, I'm a bit unclear on that, is it that if I use this, and something else pulls in the old API, I have to use an excludes somewhere?

Comment: Indeed this is the best way, but be warned that this may work with Maven 3.0.x https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5255

Comment: Also when you re-compile make sure you run a clean install (`mvn clean install`) otherwise all sorts of caching issues may occur

Comment: FYI, the most recent version is `javax.servlet-api-3.1.0`. Just be sure your Servlet container can handle that version. For example [Version 8 of Tomcat can handle 3.1](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html).

Comment: Evidently, this changed from servlet-api 2.5 to 3.x. And I overlooked the artifact name because they're so similar! It changed from `servlet-api` to `javax.servlet-api`. Thank you, thank you!

Comment: @Eugen - what is running is different because you only compile against the spec (hence scope=provided, name includes api), while we run against an implementation (installed server side, or supplied using scope=runtime, name includes - imply).

Answer (score 38):

Or you can use the Central Maven Repository with the Servlet 3.0 API which is also provided for the Tomcat Server 7.0.X

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.21</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

from here: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api/7.0.21/

Answer (score 28):

Here is what I use. All of these are in the Central and have sources.

**For Tomcat 7 (Java 7, Servlet 3.0)**

Note - Servlet, JSP and EL APIs are provided in Tomcat. Only JSTL (if used) needs to be bundled with the web app.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**For Tomcat 8 (Java 8, Servlet 3.1)**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This works, but the prescribed dependencies end up being in the Maven section but never included in the WAR file as they are marked as "provided". BUT ...I can never get the project to use the JARs in the Tomcat lib directory, even though I have included this Tomcat lib directory in the Eclipse build path, and they can clearly be seen there. My pom.xml can never resolve these Tomcat JARs and always requires version 3.0.1 of the servlet-api JAR from the local Maven repo, rather than the 3.0 version Tomcat supplies. I have no idea why this is ... can anyone explain?

Comment: Can you give which version of <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId> can I use for tomcat 8.5 ?

Answer (score 24):

Unfortunately, adding the javaee-(web)-api as a dependency doesn't give you the Javadoc or the Source to the Servlet Api to browse them from within the IDE. This is also the case for all other dependencies (JPA, EJB, ...)
If you need the Servlet API sources/javadoc, you can add the following to your pom.xml (works at least for JBoss&Glassfish):

Repository:

```xml
<repository>
  <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
  <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
  <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
</repository>
```

Dependency:

```xml
<!-- Servlet 3.0 Api Specification -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0.Beta2</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I completely removed the javaee-api from my dependencies and replaced it with the discrete parts (javax.ejb, javax.faces, ...) to get the sources and Javadocs for all parts of Java EE 6.

**EDIT:**

Here is the equivalent Glassfish dependency (although both dependencies should work, no matter what appserver you use).

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why do we need to specify version `1.0.0.Beta2`, if it's version `3.0` that we need? This makes it complex.

Answer (score 9):

The Apache Geronimo project provides a Servlet 3.0 API dependency on the Maven Central repo:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This works, and seems the simplest way, thanks! BTW Apache Geronimo has much more to offer: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.geronimo.specs

Answer (score 6):

Just for newcomers.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

I found an example POM for the [Servlet 3.0 API on DZone](http://ensode.net/roller/dheffelfinger/entry/maven_pom_xml_configuration_for) from September.

Suggest you use the java.net repo, at http://download.java.net/maven/2/

There are Java EE APIs in there, for example http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/javaee-web-api/6.0/ with POM that look like they might be what you're after, for example:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm guessing that the version conventions for the APIs have been changed to match the version of the overall EE spec (i.e. Java EE 6 vs. Servlets 3.0) as part of the new 'profiles'. Looking in the JAR, looks like all the 3.0 servlet stuff is in there. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, it works! The only remaining question is, if Java EE 6 Profiles replaced separate libs. (see addendum in my question)

Comment: If you depend on this, you can't make portable war (one that works on JBoss, Tomcat, Jetty, ...), because for Tomcat/Jetty, you'll need to put part of that dependency provided (servlet) and part of it not provided (cdi), which is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

A convenient way (JBoss recommended) to include Java EE 6 dependencies is demonstrated below. As a result dependencies are placed separately (not all in one jar as in javaee-web-api), source files and javadocs of the libraries are available to download from maven repository.

```xml
<properties>
    <jboss.javaee6.spec.version>2.0.0.Final</jboss.javaee6.spec.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-web-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>${jboss.javaee6.spec.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

To include individual dependencies only, `dependencyManagement` section and scope `import` can be used:

```xml
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee6-specs-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jboss.javaee6.spec.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- No need specifying version and scope. It is defaulted to version and scope from Bill of Materials (bom) imported pom. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this dependency, and dont forget to select : Include dependencies  with "provided" scope

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This is to debug in intellij, i am using jhipster

Answer (score -3):

Try this code...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Dependencies in alpha stage is not always suitable for production application.