# Maven Source for javax javaee-api 6.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, ejb

I am building a JEE6 (EJB) application with Maven. I use the maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
   <version>6.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

to get the api classes. But I am missing the api source code. (like javax.ejb ejb-api 3.0)

So the question is how do I get the source code for the JEE6 Apis (especial EJB 3.1) ?

I need it for better code complementation and documentation in Eclipse.

Comment: I don't use Maven and I'm not sure if Maven can conjure, but the core Java EE API doesn't have any source code. The source code (also of the implementation) is provided by the concrete implementations (Glassfish, JBoss AS, Tomcat, etc). If your sole purpose is to have javadocs, you could just download and attach it separately.

Comment: Found a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205768/maven-java-ee-6-web-profile-javadocs

Answer (score 0):

If you use m2e plugin in eclipse you can choose to "download sources" and/or "download javadoc" for your dependencies. http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/

Comment: The problem is that there are no sources und java doc: see this link to maven central: http://search.maven.org/#browse|-2019854530