# What are the individual maven dependencies of javaee-api-5?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, java-ee-5

I know for javaee-api-5 we can use the following [maven dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javaee/javaee-api/5):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javaee</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>5</version>
</dependency>
```

But if I don't want to use this single jar(cause there is no source or javadoc for this dependency) then what maven dependencies I need to add to get the javaee-api-5 functionality?

One such dependency might be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no such thing. By the way, why would you want the source for it? These are just the APIs. The actual implementations will come from other jars.

Comment: @meskobalazs more that source I need the javadoc. Yes you are right that the implementations come from other jars and most of them are server specific.

Comment: This answer may be useful:http://stackoverflow.com/a/6210582/2102532