# What is the equivalent of HttpServletRequest.getServletContext() in old version of java?

Tags: java, tomcat

My project is using some very old code and I can't really update it. There are some values that I would like to access in WEB-IN/web.xml/context-param. In recent version of java you could use :

```
HttpServletRequest servlet;
...
String myParam = servlet.getServletContext().getInitParameter("myParam");
```

But the method `getServletContext()` doesn't exist in my project configuration.

Is there another way to gain access to the WEB-INF/web.xml/context-param for old version of java/tomcat?

---

Tomcat Version : Apache Tomcat/6.0.37
Servlet Specification Version : 2.5 
JSP version : 2.1

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860782/request-getservletcontext-not-found-even-with-new-jar), it was introduced in Servlet 3.0

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpServletRequest request;
...    
ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
```

Comment: Or, if you have a Filter or Servlet, you can also get it from there (without starting a session)