# cannot resolve symbol 'servlet'

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets

I got this big newbie question.
When i try the following; the 'servlet' turns red and indicates 'Cannot resolve symbol 'servlet'.

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
```

I got apache tomcat running. I am a very big java newbie. Can anyone help me where to find a servlet library or something ? I googled but got no clear explanation of how to make this work.

This is the content of my web.xml file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <display-name>
        HelloWorld
    </display-name>
    <description>
        This is my first webapp
    </description>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Hello world!</servlet-name>
        <description>This is a hello world servlet</description>
        <servlet-class>servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>HelloWorldServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**EDIT:** I use the IntelliJ IDEA IDE.
And I am using Maven.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The servlet jar needs to be in your build path.

If you are using maven you could do this :

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
 <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
 <version>7.0.21</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Or use one of the providers listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979957/maven-dependency-for-servlet-3-0-api), Such as the below which is not dependent on a specific container :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're missing a classpath entry for servlet.jar. You haven't told us how you're building this, but basically you need to compile against servlet.jar. You shouldn't need to explicitly put it anywhere for *execution* time, as Tomcat should take care of that.

Comment: @BWestra: If you're 100% new to Java, then I'd suggest starting off with simpler programs instead of servlets. Learn the basics through simple console applications. How you add a library to your classpath depends on how you're developing - you haven't told us anything about whether you're using an IDE, compiling from the command line, using Ant, Maven, whatever.

Comment: @BWestra: Well if you're working with Maven, you should know how to work with dependencies in general - and you need the servlet dependencies, basically. I don't use Maven myself, but NimChimpsky's answer looks like it's along the right lines. I'd suggest trying to use a dependency which *isn't* Tomcat-specific though.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing [Servlet jar](http://www.findjar.com/jar/javax.servlet/jars/servlet-api-2.3.jar.html) in your classpath.add the same jar in your classpath.

If you are using Eclipse ,right click on the project.

```
-->Properties --->Java build path --->select Libraries
```

add jar there.

Comment: nope i use ÍntelliJ but i already got it working I don't even know how to be honest i tried several stuff and suddenly it worked.

Comment: Thank you for the link of Servlet jar and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The first time used IntelliJ IDEA I have the same issue, but I think the principle should be the as Eclipse, just configure our needed jar file to the external library.

Go to "File" ----> "project structure" ----> "Library",then click the <kbd>➕</kbd> button and add the needed jar.

Can not find Servlet seems you lost the `server-api.jar` file,just put it into your library. And if you want to build a j2ee project,simple that file shall make no sense.

So just put the whole local tomcat/lib jar file to your project and the function is the same as eclipse(configure build path--> runtime server...).

Answer (score 0):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello world!</servlet-name>
    <description>This is a hello world servlet</description>
    <servlet-class>servlet</servlet-class> <--here is full name of your servlet class.
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name><--here must be match <servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>HelloWorldServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```