# Servlet cannot be resolved in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets, tomcat7

For some reason idea lights dispatcher servlet and when I launch tomcat get the 404 error. I`m using spring mvc and Maven, here is the picture of web.xml [image: web.xml]
Appreciate every answer=)
webapp/web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern

Comment: also I checked [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479245/cannot-resolve-symbol-servlet) and it does not seem to be working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem, was using the `tomcat7-maven-plugin` with compile version of `maven-compiler-plugin` 1.8, after changing it to 1.7 the problem gone.
However is there any similar solutions to `tomcat7-maven-plugin`?, cause I didnt find `tomcat8-maven-plugin` in internet

Thanks everyone for participation

Comment: I just recently had this issue.  I solved it by updating the java.version in the pom and then recompiling.  Then the error went away.

Answer (score 2):

Open settings below:
Project settings -> Facets -> Web -> Deployment Descriptors

check the path here and ensure it's available. If not, click the green + to add your web module path.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add servlet mapping also and then add `spring-webmvc-version.jar` in classpath

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: do you have servlet.jar also in your claspath

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem. It turned out that I was using an old companies settings.xml file for Maven user settings file. If someone is having this problem try using the Maven template users file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add spring mvc.jar file (if you are using spring and mvc) to the class libraries
2. Make sure that [name]-sevlet.xml file is set properly.
   use name inside the  "sevlet-name" name "servlet-name" in the web.xml.

Answer (score -1):

I add the path for Web module. Using Intellij click project structure and then select Facets. Deployment Descriptors probably must be empty(its not good), so add the path.