# Maven automatically removes trailing zeroes in dependency version (javax.servlet-api)

Tags: java, maven, servlets, dependencies, servlet-3.0

I am trying to add the *javax.servlet-api* project to my Maven Java project (see [this link](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22javax.servlet%22%20AND%20a%3A%22javax.servlet-api%22) for more information about versions for this dependency). I want to add version *3.1.0* to my project. So naturally, I add this dependency to my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

However, when Maven tries to download the jar/pom files for this artifact, it gets an error because it automatically converts version *3.1.0* to *3.1*, which is not its actual version, and it cannot find that version of the artifact in the central Maven repo:

```
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1/javax.servlet-api-3.1.pom
[WARNING] The POM for javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1/javax.servlet-api-3.1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my-java-project: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example.myproject:my-project:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

Does anyone know how I can tell Maven to not strip off trailing zeroes in the version tag of a dependency in my pom.xml file? Any other workaround known?

**NOTE:** I did check out this SOF post ([Maven dependency for Servlet 3.0 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979957/maven-dependency-for-servlet-3-0-api)), but this author's solution was to use a `<scope>provided</scope>` dependency for servlet-api, which I do not have interest in doing becuase I want to avoid needing to use the *provided* scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it gets an error because it automatically converts version 3.1.0 to 3.1

That is something impossible. Maven will never convert version numbers ( with the exception of snapshots ). It will always download the version that you specify in the `pom.xml` regardless the version actually exists or not. You can test this by writing a bogus number in the version area of the tag and then fire the `mvn install` command, you will see that it will try to download that version and then fail.

To debug your problem, first verify that you have the correct maven entry in the pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Secondly , I would advise you to delete the folder `~/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/` to remove any bad jar and thus force maven to re-download all the javax.servlet jars

Comment: Deleting the `~/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/` and re-running `mvn clean install` seemed to do the trick. It was able to download version "3.1.0" of javax.servlet. Thank you for the help.